# Question R string manipulation, remove duplicates and merge/aggregate

Tags: r, string, aggregate

I have a question regarding to R and changing strings. I want for the column taste, that every row has only one name and that duplicates are removed. Then I also want the sweets of duplicated tastes merged.I included before and after pictures as well.
How can I change that not manually but with something like aggregate or splitstring?
The before and after pictures show how it should look like.

```
    taste=c("Smarties, Strawberry","Smarties")
    sweets=c("IceCream","Chocolate")
    Dessert=data.frame(taste,sweets)
```

Before:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQAW2.png]

After:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVidE.png]

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you are asking? For example, why does your after photo (row 1, col 2) have "IceCream, Chocolate"... we are missing some rules here.

Comment: Thats how the data frame should look like in the end. I don't get how I can change the data frame in such a way, that Smarties could be IceCream or Chocolate (that's why there is "IceCream, Chocolate". And Strawberry can only be IceCream.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But why? What rules are you trying to follow here. If you want code that is generalizable, there has to be some rule. For example, does the first element in `sweets` ALWAYS go before the latter elements (separated by a comma)? If not, when does it not?

Comment: the order is not important according to the elements, which are seperated by a comma. Like if there is (IceCream, Chocolate) or (Chocolate, IceCream) that doesn't matter. What is important, is that in taste there is each taste only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` on the 'taste' column to split the elements by the delimiter `,`, then grouped by 'taste', `paste` the 'sweets' in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Dessert %>%
    separate_rows(taste) %>% 
    group_by(taste) %>%
    summarise(sweets = toString(sweets))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  taste      sweets             
#* <chr>      <chr>              
#1 Smarties   IceCream, Chocolate
#2 Strawberry IceCream
```

---

Or in `base R`, use `strsplit` to split the 'taste' into a `list` of `vector`s, set the names of the `list` with the 'sweets' column, convert to a two column data.frame with `stack` and use `aggregate` to do a group by `paste` (`toString` - `paste(., collapse=', ')`)

```
aggregate(ind ~ values, stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(Dessert$taste), 
         ",\\s*"), Dessert$sweets)), FUN = toString)
```